# Angular 5 - Data binding not working

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-template

I'm having an extremely weird problem. I have a component to which I'm passing input data. Now I'm getting the input data in the component, but when I bind it in html, it just doesn't display, although I'm sure it's accessible there.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="structuredBranches && structuredBranches.length">
  <p>This is branch length {{structuredBranches.length}}</p>
```

with the above code, I'm able to see "This is branch length" but not the length itself. Since I'm also using ngIf that means structuredBranches variable was accessible and after that angular let the next line run.

I'm absolutely clueless why it's behaving this way. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Any errors in the console ?

Comment: Nope, nothing that's the first thing I checked ;)

Comment: What is the type of  `structuredBranches` .

Comment: What's the structure of this object?

Comment: It's an array of objects

Comment: In your component, try to initiate your array variable something like this => structuredBranches: any[] = [];

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4npsww

Comment: Found the bug, down below that code, I was using a object variable which was null, so there was javascript null error, but it was failing silently.